# PySpark create new column with mapping from a dict

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 1.6, I have a Spark `DataFrame column` (named let's say `col1`) with values A, B, C, DS, DNS, E, F, G and H. I want to create a new column (say `col2`) with the values from the `dict` here below. How do I map this? (e,g. 'A' needs to be mapped to 'S' etc.)

```py
dict = {'A': 'S', 'B': 'S', 'C': 'S', 'DS': 'S', 'DNS': 'S', 'E': 'NS', 'F': 'NS', 'G': 'NS', 'H': 'NS'}
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Inefficient solution with UDF (version independent):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def translate(mapping):
    def translate_(col):
        return mapping.get(col)
    return udf(translate_, StringType())

df = sc.parallelize([('DS', ), ('G', ), ('INVALID', )]).toDF(['key'])
mapping = {
    'A': 'S', 'B': 'S', 'C': 'S', 'DS': 'S', 'DNS': 'S', 
    'E': 'NS', 'F': 'NS', 'G': 'NS', 'H': 'NS'}

df.withColumn("value", translate(mapping)("key"))
```

with the result:

```
+-------+-----+
|    key|value|
+-------+-----+
|     DS|    S|
|      G|   NS|
|INVALID| null|
+-------+-----+
```

Much more efficient (**Spark >= 2.0, Spark < 3.0**) is to create a `MapType` literal:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit
from itertools import chain

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*mapping.items())])

df.withColumn("value", mapping_expr.getItem(col("key")))
```

with the same result:

```
+-------+-----+
|    key|value|
+-------+-----+
|     DS|    S|
|      G|   NS|
|INVALID| null|
+-------+-----+
```

but more efficient execution plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [key#15, keys: [B,DNS,DS,F,E,H,C,G,A], values: [S,S,S,NS,NS,NS,S,NS,S][key#15] AS value#53]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[key#15]
```

compared to UDF version:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [key#15, pythonUDF0#61 AS value#57]
+- BatchEvalPython [translate_(key#15)], [key#15, pythonUDF0#61]
   +- Scan ExistingRDD[key#15]
```

In **Spark >= 3.0**  `getItem` should be replaced with `__getitem__` (`[]`), i.e:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit
from itertools import chain

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*mapping.items())])

df.withColumn("value", mapping_expr[col("key")])
```

Comment: zero323 - Having trouble understanding this method. ```withColumn``` takes a ```colName``` string as first arg, but you're passing a map value instead of key?

```df.withColumn("value", mapping_expr.getItem(col("key")))```

Also result from ```create_map``` looks like this and calling getItem() like above is not working for me:
 
 
```Column<b'map(key_a, val_a, key_b, val_b)'>```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution ! It works like a charm. Also if you wish to do the same behaviour with a list instead of the fict :  

`from pyspark.sql.functions import array`
For example:
`values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
`indexing_expr = array(*[lit(x) for x in values]) # The * is important`
`df.withColumn("value", indexing_expr[col("index")])`

Answer (score 43):

Sounds like the simplest solution would be to use the replace function:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace

```
mapping= {
        'A': '1',
        'B': '2'
    }
df2 = df.replace(to_replace=mapping, subset=['yourColName'])
```

Comment: The problem here is that this will not create a new column, it will replace the values in the original one.

Comment: Couldn't you just first copy the old values into a new column first, then use this function?

Comment: Replace also requires the new values to be the same type as the original column.

Comment: I like the shortness of this solution. If you want an extra column just copy the column 
 using `.withColumn("newColumn", "column_to_copy")` or so - The example just provides the minimum code you need to know to do this yourselfs :) Sometimes I think comments on SO are just used to be pedantic..

Comment: if someone could benchmark this solution against the accepted one, that would be very helpful. I implemented the `replace` but I does slow down my code considerably which puzzles me.

Answer (score 4):

**Without** `itertools` import, **list comprehensions** deal with it very nicely.

Map from dict:

```py
F.create_map([F.lit(x) for i in dic.items() for x in i])
```

Extracting values:

```py
F.create_map([F.lit(x) for i in dic.items() for x in i])[F.col('col1')]
```

---

Full test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A',), ('E',), ('INVALID',)],
    ['col1']
)
dic = {'A': 'S', 'B': 'S', 'E': 'NS'}

map_col = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for i in dic.items() for x in i])
df = df.withColumn('col2', map_col[F.col('col1')])

df.show()
# +-------+----+
# |   col1|col2|
# +-------+----+
# |      A|   S|
# |      E|  NS|
# |INVALID|null|
# +-------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a map col from a nested dictionary you can use this:

```py
def create_map(d,):
    if type(d) != dict:
        return F.lit(d)

    level_map = []
    for k in d:
        level_map.append(F.lit(k))
        level_map.append(create_map(d[k]))
    return F.create_map(level_map)

d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 'blah'}}
print(create_map(d)) # <- Column<b'map(a, 1, b, map(c, 2, d, blah))'>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function which convert dictionary into case syntax in Spark SQL

```
func_mapper = lambda dic,col,default : f"(CASE {col} WHEN " + " WHEN ".join([ f"'{k}' THEN '{v}'" for (k,v) in dic.items() ]) + f" ELSE '{default}' END)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs to map null values as well, [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42983199/5289570) didn't work for me. The problem with map type is it can't handle null-valued keys.

But we can replace it with a generated CASE WHEN statement and use `isNull` instead of `== None`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

d = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('A', ), ('B', ), (None, ), ('INVALID', )]).toDF(['key'])

mapping = {'A': '1', 'B': '2', None: 'empty'}
map_tuples = list(mapping.items())

def email_eq_null_safe(key):
    if key is None:
        return F.col('key').isNull()
    else:
        return F.col('key') == key

'''
F.when(
    F.col('key') == key1,
    value1
).when(
    F.col('key') == key2,
    value2
)....
'''
whens = reduce(
    lambda prev, nxt: prev.when(email_eq_null_safe(nxt[0]), nxt[1]), 
    map_tuples[1:],
    F.when(email_eq_null_safe(map_tuples[0][0]), map_tuples[0][1])
)

d.select(
    'key',
    whens.alias('value')
).show()

+-------+-----+
|    key|value|
+-------+-----+
|      A|    1|
|      B|    2|
|   null|empty|
|INVALID| null|
+-------+-----+
```