# Using MapType literal to create new column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following `pyspark.DataFrame`

```
+---+--------+--------+--------------+
|SEX|_AGEG5YR|_IMPRACE|       _LLCPWT|
+---+--------+--------+--------------+
|  2|    11.0|     1.0| 79.4259469451|
|  2|    10.0|     1.0| 82.1648291655|
|  2|    11.0|     2.0| 55.7851100058|
|  2|    13.0|     1.0|115.9818718258|
|  2|    12.0|     1.0|194.7566575195|
+---+--------+--------+--------------+
```

**I want to create a new column based on SEX column** 
As suggested [by this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42983199/9720263), I have defined a `MapType` literal as follow

```
brfss_mapping = {
    "SEX": {
        1: "Male",
        2: "Female",
        9: "Refused"
    }
}
brfss_sex_mapping = create_map(
    [lit(x) for x in chain(*brfss_mapping["SEX"].items())]
)
```

Now, when I use `withColumn` and `brfss_sex_mapping.getItem(...)` with constant value such as below

```
brfss_dmy = brfss_dmy.withColumn(
    "SEX_2",
    brfss_sex_mapping.getItem(1)
)
```

I get the expected result

```
+---+--------+--------+--------------+-----+                                    
|SEX|_AGEG5YR|_IMPRACE|       _LLCPWT|SEX_2|
+---+--------+--------+--------------+-----+
|  1|    13.0|     1.0|381.8001043164| Male|
|  2|    10.0|     1.0| 82.1648291655| Male|
|  1|    11.0|     1.0|279.1864457296| Male|
|  1|    10.0|     1.0| 439.024136158| Male|
|  2|     8.0|     1.0| 372.921644978| Male|
+---+--------+--------+--------------+-----+
```

However, when I try to pass the appropriate column as follow (again, as it is suggested in the previous answer)

```
brfss_dmy = brfss_dmy.withColumn(
    "SEX_2",
    brfss_sex_mapping.getItem(col("SEX"))
)
```

I get the following 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.Column SEX`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the example you provided. I'm using Spark 2.4

Comment: @Lamanus ```brfss_sex_mapping.getItem("SEX")``` returns null for every row. I think it tries to access the value whose key is "SEX" which if not defined.

Comment: @blackbishop I'm using Spark 3.0

Comment: @PierrePasquet https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42983199/revisions

Comment: I was wrong, sorry, The above link is really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in Spark 3.0, we can no longer pass a column to `getItem` function but I couldn't find any reference in the code or documentation.

You can use [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.element_at) instead:

```
df.withColumn("SEX_2", element_at(brfss_sex_mapping, col("SEX")).show()
```

Or access value as an array :

```
df.withColumn("SEX_2", brfss_sex_mapping[col("SEX")]).show()
```

In Scala:

```
df.withColumn("SEX_2", element_at(brfss_sex_mapping, $"SEX")).show()
df.withColumn("SEX_2", brfss_sex_mapping($"SEX")).show()
```