# Cross dataframe with dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following dictionaries inside variables:

```
sk_channel_types = {"facebooknotification": 2,
                    "facebookmessenger": 9,
                    "onsitenotification": 3,
                    "pushnotification": 6,
                    "pushnotificationmessage": 6,
                    "lightbox": 4,
                    "onsitemessage": 7,
                    "mailmessage": 1}

sk_story_types = {"welcome": 7,
                  "rescue": 13,
                  "frequency": 4,
                  "abandoncart": 6,
                  "pricedrop": 16,
                  "manual": 5,
                  "searchbykeyword": 30,
                  "sazonality": 31,
                  "bestdayforpurchase": 28,
                  "pricechange": 32,
                  "availability": 33,
                  "toptrending": 1,
                  "toptrendingbycluster": 2,
                  "toptrendingwithpricelimit": 3,
                  "frequencyview": 4,
                  "manualnotification": 5,
                  "trending": 9,
                  "toptrendingbykeyword": 9}
```

And this is my current spark dataframe:

| ID | StoryType | Type | StoryId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | AbandonCart | MailMessage | 56465465456456456465 |
| lçdkçlskdçlsdkçlskdç | ManualNotification | MailMessage | 60983099380938390833 |
| uahuahuahauhauahuaha | ManualNotification | MailMessage | 49438093890484984949 |
| sklçskçlskdkcnopeieo | ManualNotification | MailMessage | 93084098409840984098 |
| 2d5fe941380938098948 | ManualNotification | MailMessage | 49809380398094894844 |
| 9883jkjd3eu0dj0j3930 | ManualNotification | MailMessage | 636f50c9380938093893 |

I need to replace the StoryType and Type columns with their respective numbers, as per the variables, like this:

| ID | StoryType | Type | StoryId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrst | 6 | 1 | 56465465456456456465 |
| lçdkçlskdçlsdkçlskdç | 5 | 1 | 60983099380938390833 |
| uahuahuahauhauahuaha | 5 | 1 | 49438093890484984949 |
| sklçskçlskdkcnopeieo | 5 | 1 | 93084098409840984098 |
| 2d5fe941380938098948 | 5 | 1 | 49809380398094894844 |
| 9883jkjd3eu0dj0j3930 | 5 | 1 | 636f50c9380938093893 |

How can I do this? Can I use a case with low? I'm new to Pyspark.

Comment: If you invert those dictionaries (that is, `{2: "facebooknotification", 4: "lightbox",...}`), then it's trivial to use `apply` to lookup the new values.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980704/pyspark-create-new-column-with-mapping-from-a-dict

Comment: @ScootCork Did not work :(

Comment: USE `from itertools import chain`
`from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit`
`m_expr1 = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*sk_channel_types.items())])`
`m_expr2 = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*sk_story_types.items())])`
`df = df.withColumn('Type', m_expr1[lower(df['Type'])]).withColumn('StoryType', m_expr2[lower(df['StoryType'])])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the dictionaries are small the efficient way is to make them broadcasted dataset and join them to the dataset.

Comment: Perfect, I achieved :D