# PySpark: Too many WHEN statements?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark v2.4.0 and I occurred a strange phenomenon:

I have rather simple dataframe function and use it on some dataframe called "new":

```
from product_mapping import product_mapping
    
new2 = product_mapping(new)   
new2.show()
```

product mapping (it's a separate python script due to length of the statement)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def product_mapping(df):

    df = df.withColumn('PRODUCT',  F.when((df.var1 == "301") & (df.var2 == 0) & (df.var3 == 30), F.lit('101')) 
                              .when((df.var1 == "301") & (df.var2 == 1) & (df.var3 == 30), F.lit('102'))  
                              .when((df.var1 == "302") & (df.var2 == 0) & (df.var3 == 31), F.lit('103'))  
                              .when((df.var1 == "302") & (df.var2 == 1) & (df.var3 == 31), F.lit('104'))  
                              .when((df.var1 == "303") & (df.var2 == 0) & (df.var3 == 61), F.lit('105'))  
                              .when((df.var1 == "303") & (df.var2 == 0) & (df.var3 == 32), F.lit('106'))  
                              .when((df.var1 == "303") & (df.var2 == 1) & (df.var3 == 32), F.lit('107'))  
                              .when((df.var1 == "303") & (df.var2 == 1) & (df.var3 == 61), F.lit('108'))  
                              .when((df.var1 == "304") & (df.var2 == 0) & (df.var3 == 69), F.lit('109')) 
    (many more WHEN lines) 
                              .when((df.var1 == "304") & (df.var2 == 1) & (df.var3 == 69), F.lit('205')))

    return df
```

In total I have some > 150 lines, but the code does not seem to work; it throws up error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1754.showString.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.extract16BitValue(CodeContext.java:720)
        at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:561)
```

However, when I shorten the statement to let's say 5 WHEN statements, the code works fine ... so is there a max number of WHEN statements to use? And how to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: you could concatenate the var columns and create a mapping with the desired output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980704/pyspark-create-new-column-with-mapping-from-a-dict

Comment: Hi, okay yes, looks like a possible solution, but how would the mapping look like with multiple arguments? Sorry never used this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents: (The idea here is to concatenate three variables and then map based on the dictionary of key-value pairs)

1. Declare the function as follows:

   ```
    def product_mapping(df):

        conditions = {  '301-1-30' : '102',
                        '302-0-31' : '103',
                        '302-1-31' : '104',
                        '303-0-61' : '105',
                        '301-0-30' : '106',
                        '303-1-32' : '107',
                        '303-1-61' : '108',
                        '304-0-69' : '109',
                        '301-0-31' : '114'
                    }

        df = df.withColumn('PRODUCT', fx.concat(df.var1, fx.lit('-'), df.var2, fx.lit('-'),df.var3))
        df1 = df.replace(to_replace=conditions, subset=['PRODUCT'])\
                .withColumn('PRODUCT',fx.col('PRODUCT').cast(IntegerType()))
        return df1
   ```
2. Create a data frame assuming it has 3 required columns - var1, var2, var3

   ```
    new  = spark.createDataFrame([(301,0,30),(301,1,30),(301,0,31)],schema = ['var1','var2','var3'])
   ```
3. Call the function and print the returned data frame:

   ```
    new2 = product_mapping(new)   
    new2.show()
   ```

Please refer the below screenshot for reference:
[image]