# create new spark column based on dictionary values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have a Spark DF in this format:

| currency | value |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 1.00 |
| EUR | 2.00 |

And a dictionary with current currency exchanges 
(e.g - `{EUR: 1.00, USD: 0.90}`).

And I want to add another column, say `value_eur`, based on that dict. How would I go on in doing that?

I tried the function

```
raw_df.withColumn("value_eur", raw_df.value * currency_exchanges[raw_df.currency])
```

but it gives me Error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Column'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark create new column with mapping from a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980704/pyspark-create-new-column-with-mapping-from-a-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below implementation -

**Input DF**-

```
from pysprl.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("currency", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value", DoubleType(), True)
])

data = [("USD", 1.00), ("EUR", 2.00)]
raw_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

**Required Output**-

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

currency_exchanges = {'EUR': 1.00, 'USD': 0.90}
currency_df = spark.createDataFrame(list(currency_exchanges.items()), ['currency', 'exchange_rate'])


result_df = raw_df.join(broadcast_currency_df, 'currency', 'left') \
    .withColumn('value_eur', when(col('currency') == 'EUR', col('value')).otherwise(col('value') * col('exchange_rate'))) \
    .drop('exchange_rate')

result_df.show()

+--------+-----+---------+
|currency|value|value_eur|
+--------+-----+---------+
|     USD|  1.0|      0.9|
|     EUR|  2.0|      2.0|
+--------+-----+---------+
```

Here I've created another `currency_df` using the dictionary and have joined `raw_df` with `currency_df` for the required use case.